# How to pass along a variable during Rails Ajax?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am building a rails app to import and manage emails. So I made a page that can upload excel file and preview it before they really import.

```
def import
# ...
end

def preview
# showing emails using rails ajax
end

def confirm_import
# store emails into database
end
```

Because I need to let user preview what they want to import, in action 'import' I run the ajax request 'preview'.

```
/* This is the import.html.erb */
<%= form_tag(preview_path, method: "post", remote: true) do %>
    <%= text_area_tag 'email-list' %>                   
    <%= submit_tag "Preview" %>
<% end %>
```

But after this I cannot get those emails as params['emails'].  What I do now is in 'preview.js.erb' I use javascript to store those emails in a hidden HTML tag 'result_email_list', and send them to 'confirm_import'.

```
/* in import.html.erb, after preview.js.erb is done */
<%= form_tag(confirm_import_path, method: "post") do %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :result_email_list %>
    <%= submit_tag "Confirm" %>
<% end %>
```

Is there a more Rails way to do it? Storing data in HTML seems like a pretty bad idea.

Comment: What are the `params` generated for the action import?

Comment: In 'import' there's a form ( textarea for email and a submit ) which links to 'preview', so the 'preview' can get something like params['emails'].

Comment: But after 'preview' is done, params is no longer passed.  So I had to store emails in HTML in 'preview' and let 'confirm_import' use them

Comment: Can you edit your post with the form code?

Comment: just did, sorry for not explaining well enough :(